# Render one div of child component directly in app component or root component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple components and I need to render one modal div at in main app,

tried using, but it's not working for me in react

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName()[0].appendChild();
```

Is there any way rather than putting that component directly to App

Comment: Have you looked at portals? https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: It might also help to describe the motivation here. What are you trying to achieve? There may be a more react-y way

Comment: not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but maybe you can use a `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` in your component or something to append a child to the dom once it has loaded. (https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect). Also I hope you're putting a value in `getElementsByClassName` and not just leaving it blank.